Questions about proof of all infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces have orthonormal sequences which converge weakly to $0$.
So I saw this proof of the fact that any orthonormal set in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space all otrthonormal sets converge weakly to zero. That is, if $H$ is the Hilbert space and if $\{u_n\}_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ is orthonormal, then
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \langle u_n,y \rangle = \langle 0, y \rangle \space \text{for all $y \in H$}.$$
First question is are we allowed to suppose we have a countable orthonormal set cause I thought this is only true when the Hilbert space is separable (in the Hilbert space sense in which there exists a countable set such that closure of span is the whole space) but in the definition of weak convergence were indexing over integers as we send $n$ to $\infty$ so are we just allowed to start off with a countable orthonormal set? And I understand if we have a countable orthonormal set $\{u_n\}_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ in $H$ then for each $y \in H$, one has
$$\sum_{n \in \Bbb{N}} \langle u_n,y \rangle \leq \vert \vert y \vert \vert^2.$$
Why does this imply the sum converges? And where do they use orthonormality? And I get that if the sum converges then the terms tend to zero and taking the square off tends you to $\langle 0,y \rangle$. And am I correct in assuming weak convegrence is in the inner product while strong is in the norm?

please try to restrict your post to one (main) question. There are different points you ask about which can be separately answered.


First question is are we allowed to suppose we have a countable orthonormal set cause I thought this is only true when the Hilbert space is separable (in the Hilbert space sense in which there exists a countable set such that closure of span is the whole space)

Your comment quoted above ends with "such that the closure of the span is the whole space". You're thinking of an orthonormal basis. The proof is only about an orthonormal set, which doesn't have any requirement that the span be the whole space.
A set $\Gamma\subset H$ is orthonormal or is an orthonormal set if for any $e,f\in \Gamma$, $$\langle e,f\rangle = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}1 & : e=f \\ 0 & : e \neq f.\end{array}\right.$$ No requirement on the closure of the span.
A set $\Gamma\subset H$ is an orthonormal basis for $H$ if it is an orthonormal set and the span is dense in $H$.
The inequality $$\sum_n \langle e_n,y\rangle\leqslant \|y\|^2$$ isn't correct, and doesn't even make sense in a complex Hilbert space. What we have is Bessel's inequality, which is that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\langle e_n,y\rangle|^2\leqslant \|y\|^2.$$  This implies that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\langle e_n,y\rangle|^2$ converges, since the terms are non-negative. That means $\lim_n |\langle e_n,y\rangle|^2=0$, and $\lim_n \langle e_n,y\rangle=0$ by what some folks call the "test for divergence".
Bessel's inequality follows from letting $E$ denote the closed span of $\{e_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Let $P:H\to E$ denote the orthogonal projection onto $E$ and let $Q=I_H-P$ be the complementary projection onto the orthogonal complement $E^\perp$ of $E$. By the Pythagorean theorem, $$\|y\|^2=\|Py\|^2+\|Qy\|^2\geqslant \|Py\|^2.$$
Moreover, $$Py=\sum_n \langle y,e_n\rangle e_n,$$ and again by the Pythagorean theorem, $$\|Py\|^2=\langle Py,Py\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\langle y,e_n\rangle|^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\langle e_n,y\rangle|^2.$$
To answer your final question: Yes, a sequence $(u_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in a Hilbert space $H$ is weakly null if $\lim_n \langle e_n,y\rangle=0$ for all $y\in H$. It is strongly null if $\lim_n \|e_n\|=1$.
More generally, if $X$ is a Banach space and $X^*$ denotes the space of continuous linear functionals on $X$, the weak topology on $X$ is the weakest topology on $X$ which makes each member of $X^*$ continuous. Then a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subset X$ is weakly null if and only if $\lim_n x^*(x_n)=0$ for all $x^*\in X^*$. This relates back to the definition of weak nullity in Hilbert spaces because of the Riesz representation theorem, which states that there is a bijection from $H$ onto $H^*$ given by $y\mapsto \Phi(y)$, where $\Phi(y)(x)=\langle x,y\rangle$.
